# Is there any natural blue rose?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, ethnobiology, pigmentation

I had recently read an article that the possibility of having natural blue rose is extremely rare because of the absence of delphinidin in most roses. Are all blue roses just a product of cross-breeding?

Comment: Wikipedia article on [blue roses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_rose) has a pretty comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no roses (that is, flowers of genus *Rosa* species) that naturally express a "true" blue color. Through cross-breeding, [there are lilac-mauve rose horticultural varieties](http://www.everyrose.com/everyrose/roses/browse.lasso) ("Blue Nile","Blue Moon","Lady X", etc.), and through genetic engineering (actually inserting delphinidin-producing genes) [there are mauve-lavender varieties](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2011/09/blue-roses-for-sale/) ("Applause"). The insertion of delphinidin-producing genes did not yield blue colour roses as hoped is due to the acidity of the rose petals, which itself changed the delphinidin blue to mauve-lavender instead. The next breakthrough will be to switch off the acidity of the rose petals to create a true blue rose.

**More info**

Wikipedia article [Blue Rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_rose) gives good coverage.

[Here's a nice scientific bibliography of rose pigments with some good information on blues](http://bulbnrose.x10.mx/Heredity/King/RosePigments/RosePigments.html).